# Stop a function after x seconds in a FastAPI server

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, fastapi

I have a class A with a function foo() that logs information for an infinite time.
I would like to execute this function for 30 sec, retrieving these logs. For the recovery of the logs, I base myself on [this article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/), the logs being realized at the C level.

So I realized, in addition to the code of the previous article, this portion of code, allowing to stop the execution of the function after 30 seconds.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = io.BytesIO()
    with stdout_redirector(f):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=A.foo, name="myfunc")
        p.start()
        # Cleanup
        p.join(30)
        if p.is_alive():
            # Terminate foo
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
data = f.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
```

This works fine as is.
However, I can't get this portion of the code into a fastAPI endpoint. Indeed, no matter what I try, errors around the multiprocessing appear. Either the endpoint returns nothing, or a Pickle error appears... I don't know what to do!

Here I use multiprocessing only to stop foo() after a while; maybe there is another way to avoid problems with fastAPI. Does anyone have a way to fix my problem?

## EDIT #1

Based on Brandt's suggestion, the following function was done (Using windows, I can't use signals.):

```py
@timeout_decorator.timeout(30, use_signals=False)
def run_func(func):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    with stdout_redirector(f):
       func()   
    return f.getvalue().decode('utf-8')
```

And the following endpoint :

```py
@app.get('/foo')
def get_foo():
   data = run_func(A.foo)
   return {'data' : data}
```

but the `EOFError: Ran out of input` is triggered by thetimeout_decorator module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '**timeout_decorator**' package:

- https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/

Back in the days, it provided me the solution for a similar issue; I was/am not using FastAPI, but pretty much the same thing(AFAIU).

Basically, you just decorate the function you want to stop in case it surpasses some "T-seconds" timeout. Here is the code I used it:

- https://github.com/chbrandt/eada/blob/master/eada/vo/conesearch.py#L57

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I think it is based on threads though (like my program) as I think I have had this error before, I edited my post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can override the returned error with the `timeout_exception` parameter:

```
@timeout_decorator.timeout(30, use_signals=False, timeout_exception=TimeoutError)
```

However, you may run into a different problem with the `timeout_decorator`. The usage of `use_signals=False`, in my case, caused FAST API service to shutdown after handling the timeout! This seems to be due to Fastapi thread operations as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716578/how-to-stop-execution-of-fastapi-endpoint-after-a-specified-time-to-reduce-cpu-r).

I ended up using the decorator without the `use_signals` parameter, and opening a thread to handle the method with `timeout_decorator`.