# Fastapi - reduce the wait for a response from the service

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

It is not possible to limit the response time of a request from an application. It is necessary that the service interrupt the connection after 10s.

```
command=gunicorn -w 3 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 2
```

`--timeout` is intended for another as far as I understand

Comment: You are not asking something, you are making a statement. Providing a question may help here.

Comment: How can I limit the response time from the service?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743908/17865804).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop execution of FastAPI endpoint after a specified time to reduce CPU resource usage/cost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716578/how-to-stop-execution-of-fastapi-endpoint-after-a-specified-time-to-reduce-cpu-r)

Comment: @Chris it's been a while so I've referenced your link in a vote to close as a dup