# Uvicorn no response after 275 seconds

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn

I am using FastAPI with Uvicorn. I have set --timeout-keep-alive to 600. When I run a small file, the process and response works fine. I get the 200 and the correct data. If the file is large, the requests.post keeps running for ever unless I add a timeout. I can see that the server finishes the process and gives a 200 message but it is not received by Python requests.

In order to test, in the same FastAPI app. I added a simple async function with a sleep. I found out that at exactly 275 seconds, it seems that the request losses connection with the server and does not get the response.

```
@app.get("/test/")
async def read_root():
    time.sleep(275)
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

I have read the documentation and it seems there is no any other timeout. Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: You would need to adjust the `read` timeout on client side - see [Python requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/advanced/#timeouts). You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743908/17865804) helpful.

Comment: Hello Chris. Thanks for your answer. I have checked the links and I tried adding a timeout on the client side which effectively stops the process but does not get the OK (200) response from the server. I also tried httpx as suggested in one of the links but does not work either. Uploading the file works fine but after the processing the file about 5 minutes later seems there is no communication between client and Uvicorn server does not get response.  I also tried using 'requests.Session()' and addding 'keep_alive = TCPKeepAliveAdapter(idle=120, count=20, interval=30)'. It did not work either.