# Is it possible to yield one compressed file at a time in FastAPI into a single archive using StreamingResponse?

Tags: python, zip, streaming, fastapi, yield

I have code that creates a zip archive of files and streams it. The problem is, for large requests, this means there can be minutes of processing time before the data is streamed, making cancelling requests problematic, since the Python will continue to run. Ideally I would yield each compressed file, one a time through a generator function, and the user receive the whole zip archive still, thus making cancellation of requests more robust.

I have a minimal working example. If the function yields a single file (N=1), it works fine. If you want to yield 2 or more (N>=2), the zip is corrupt. Here is a minimal working example:

```
# test endpoint
from fastapi import APIRouter, Path
from numpy import random
import io, zipfile
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

router = APIRouter(tags=["Make files"])

# make some fake data and zip, then yield 
def make_data(N):

    """
    Make fake data.
    """    

    CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024

    for n in range(N):

        content = random.random(100)
        name = f'{n:02}.txt'

        # Create new in-memory zip file for each file
        s = io.BytesIO()
        with zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=2) as zf:
            # Add file content to the in-memory zip file
            zf.writestr(name, content)

        # Seek to the beginning of the in-memory zip file
        s.seek(0)

        # Yield the content of the in-memory zip file for the current file
        while chunk := s.read(CHUNK_SIZE):
            yield chunk

# streamingresponse
def stream_data(N):

    """
    Stream the files.
    """

    return StreamingResponse(
        make_data(N), media_type="application/zip",
        headers={"Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename=download.zip"})

# endpoint
@router.get("/{N}")
async def yield_files(
    N: int = Path(..., decription="random files to make")):

    return stream_data(N)
```

Is there a simple change that could be made to allow this script to work?

Comment: zip-files aren't designed to be appended to each other with separate headers into a single stream; you might have more luck with something like the `tar` file format, but most end users won't really know what to do with that.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77861754/17865804) helpful

Comment: @Chris This is what I previously had, but used tempfile to better manage RAM. But if the user requests a lot of data, the processing becomes long, and if they terminate their request, the script creating the zips would carry on (not good!). I am trying to overcome this problem

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77862153/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743908/17865804) helpful as well

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) might help too

Answer (score 0):

zip files can be streamed, but Python's `ZipFile` does not appear to support streaming. You could perhaps link to or adapt the C code in [zipflow](https://github.com/madler/zipflow) to stream zip files.